# While loop with nested .forEach() produces no-loop-func es-lint warning

Tags: javascript, eslint

This is a javascript question. I learned a sorting pattern in a Ruby tutorial a little while ago, now I'm trying to reuse the same pattern in javascript:

```
const sortMyArray = (someArr) => {

let arrToSort = [...someArr];

let sorted = false;

  while(!sorted) {
   sorted = true;

    array1.forEach((foo) => {

      array2.forEach((bar, i) => {

        if (foo.attr !== bar.attr) {

          let plucked = arrayToSort.splice(i, 1)
          arrayToSort.push(plucked[0])
          sorted = false
        }
      })
    })
  }

}
```

I'm comfortable with this pattern and would like to keep it. I've had to configure es-lint to ignore `no-loop-func` at the top of the file (the offending variable is the `sorted` variable being passed from outside of the inner loop), but I'd like to avoid doing this with javascript as the warning is useful, I just don't think it helps with this example.

Is there any other way to achieve this same sort that plays nicely in javascript?

Comment: Btw this is a very inefficient sorting strategy

Answer (score 0):

https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-loop-func

The warning should be more specific that it's about the `sorted` variable:

> Function declared in a loop contains unsafe references to variable(s) 'sorted'. (no-loop-func)

What is doesn't like here is that there's a function inside a loop that modifies `sorted`, which is outside--it's not aware that this function is guaranteed to only run only once within your while loop.

Anyway, you can resolve this by instead using:

```
for (const foo of array1) {
```

or if you need the index (such as for the second loop):

```
for (let i = 0; i < array2.length; i++) {
    const bar = array2[i];
```

Now you are no longer creating a function inside a loop that uses an external variable.

Comment: Thanks I was just editing to specify it was the sorted variable